# Grouping Within a SSRS Expression

Tags: reporting-services, expression, grouping, average, iif

I have a SSRS expression where I'm calculating and an average setup time, but because of multiple, and different, postings against each order I'm needing to only take the average setup times for unique orders.  Because of the need for other parts of the report to include ALL postings I cannot group or filter out the multiple order postings anywhere but this single expression. So I have the following expression:

```
=AVG(iif(IsNumeric(Fields!Setup.Value), CDbl(Fields!Setup.Value), 0))
```

And I'm essentially needing the proper syntax for the above expression rewritten to...psuedocode incoming...

```
=IIf((Fields!Order_Number.Value) is unique), AVG(iif(IsNumeric(Fields!Setup.Value), CDbl(Fields!Setup.Value), 0), else nothing)
```

I'm pretty sure a CountDistinct clause will resolve this issue, but I'm having difficulty finding the proper syntax.

Comment: Do you have permission to edit the query for the data source?

Comment: I do, and I could filter only unique order_number in the main query, but I'm needing all the individual entries for other portions of the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a column to identify a unique row for each order:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YourOrderID ORDER BY YourOrderID) as RowNumber
```

Add a calculated field to your dataset. Let’s call it “FilteredSetup”:

```
=IIf(Fields!RowNumber.Value = 1, Fields!Setup.Value, Nothing)
```

Now you can refer to this new column in your report and it will aggregate correctly:

```
=Sum(Fields!FilteredSetup.Value)
```

Comment: Thank you.  That was really close.  Just ran into the error about trying to use an aggregate function on a data type that wasn't valid because the data is stored as a nvarchar.  Easy fix for that:
=SUM(iif(IsNumeric(Fields!FilteredSetup.Value), CDbl(Fields!FilteredSetup.Value), 0))